# How to lookup EJB using JMS and CDI 1.2

Tags: java, queue, jms, cdi, wildfly-10

I am migrating my project to **Wildfly10** and using **cdi-api 1.2**.

I have been using this structure to get the **beanManager** and then lookup some resources (example EJBs).

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;

public abstract class ServiceLocator {
    //....
    private BeanManager getBeanManager() throws NamingException {
        return CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    }
    public static <T> T lookup(Class<T> clazz) {
        BeanManager manager = this.getBeanManager(); 
    //...
}
```

This works fine using in a **Servlet** or a **Filter**.

However, when I use this same function in a **MDB JMS** like:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = MyQueueProcessor.QUEUE_NAME, 
//...
public class RecebimentoMensagemCAM0021MDB {
    @Override
    protected void process(Object obj) {
        MyServices service = ServiceLocator.lookup(MyServices.class);
   //...
```

Occur this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0039: Singleton not set for 
ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra:main" 
from local module loader @629f0666 (finder: local module finder 
@1bc6a36e (roots: /home/confidence/wildfly-
10.1.0.Final/modules,/home/confidence/wildfly-
10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base)). This means that you are 
trying to access a weld deployment with a Thread Context ClassLoader 
that is not associated with the deployment.
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.ModuleGroupSingletonProvider$TCCLSingleton.get(ModuleGroupSingletonProvider.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.ModuleGroupSingletonProvider$TCCLSingleton.get(ModuleGroupSingletonProvider.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldProvider.getCDI(WeldProvider.java:61)
    at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:60)
    at br.com.project.ServiceLocator.getBeanManager(ServiceLocator.java:xx)
    at br.com.project.ServiceLocator.lookup(ServiceLocator.java:xx)
```

Anyone could help how to make this lookup works in the JMS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a blind shot, but still - can you try **NOT** to use `CDI.current()` from MDB? Instead, try simply `@Inject BeanManager bm` directly into MDB. MDB is (from CDI standpoint) so called `InjectionTarget` hence still eligible to be injected into.

Comment: I tried to use @Inject, but it returned an null object

Answer (score 0):

You can get an instance of your services using just CDI, not is necessary your locator, eg:

MyServices myServices = CDI.select(MyServices.class).get()

http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/learn/userguide/CDI-user-guide.html#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup

Comment: I had the same exception:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0039: Singleton not set for ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra:main" from local module loader @133e16fd (finder: local module finder
  at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:55)
  at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldProvider.getCDI(WeldProvider.java:61)
  at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:60)

Comment: please, post your pom.xml

Comment: I have a very large project with a lot of submodules. What information would be helpful?

Comment: Are you declaring any CDI 1.2 library or some implementation like weld in dependencies?

Comment: Yeah, my root project has `<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>`